# Ajax call back function is not working

Tags: jquery, angularjs, ajax

When I am send post request through Ajax however service posted data successfully with success responsonse in firebug but function given inside success: not working. Please review below code I used for post data.

```
    jQuery.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: postUrl,
        data: formString,
        success: function(data) {
            console.log("successfully saved");
            success();
        },
        dataType: 'json',
        contentType: 'application/json'
    });
```

Function Success inside success: property not working even if data saved successfully.

Please suggest me proper way to do this.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to use `console.log(data)` to see the error in your console.

Comment: Yes I am using the same but even if I don't get any response as my servie saved data succefully

Comment: I have just concern about why i am not getting responsie in success section even my post service saved successfully I got success from network tab in firebug but only I don't get any function call or console log in sucess: